# File goes back to blank when editing a seperate field

Tags: vb.net

This program is to store information of the customer who purchases a ticket on a flight

```
Public DestinationTick As String
            Public PlaneTick As String
            Public TimeTick As String
            Public NameTick As String
            Public DayTick As String
            Public Stockitems() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("AM830.csv")
            Public SortedStock(Stockitems.Length - 1)
            Public Stocktypes(Stockitems.Length - 1) As Flight

    Public Structure Flight
        Public Destination As String
        Public Plane As String
        Public Time As String
        Public Name As String
        Public Day As String
        Public Address As String
    End Structure


''' when they press the button names P1A1
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText("AM830.csv", "")
        If P1A1.BackColor = Color.Red Then
            Stocktypes(0).Destination = GlobalDestination
            Stocktypes(0).Plane = GlobalPlane
            Stocktypes(0).Time = GLobalTime
            Stocktypes(0).Name = GlobalName
            Stocktypes(0).Day = GlobalDay
            Stocktypes(0).Address = GlobalAddress
            P1A1.Enabled = False
        End If


For Each item In Stocktypes
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("AM830.txt", item.Destination & "," & item.Plane & "," & item.Time & "," & item.Name & "," & item.Day & "," & item.Address)
        Next
```

This code is used to edit a text file with csv format which does work and i can edit 1 up to all of the fields at once. However when i close the program and open it again to further edit the file it will edit another field but deletes the rest of the fields. For example:

First time editing

```
Ambuti,Plane 1,8:30,Monday,1,2
Ambuti,Plane 1,8:30,Monday,1,2
Ambuti,Plane 1,8:30,Monday,1,2
Ambuti,Plane 1,8:30,Monday,1,2
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
Ambuti,Plane 1,8:30,Monday,1,2
,,,,,
```

Close the program and open it again to edit it a second time
if i were to change the fifth line it shows up as:

```
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
Ambuti,Plane 1,8:30,Monday,1,2
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
```

Where as it should have just left the other fields and edited the fifth line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `System.IO.File.WriteAllText` which;

> **creates** a file, writes the specified string to the file

This is your problem.

You are needing to open the stream and update the existing file - something like this should help:

```
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = 
        new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"FilePath.csv", true))
    {
        file.WriteLine("New ticket information");
    }
```

[MSDN Link for more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/8bh11f1k.aspx)